# edit and save the dynamically render text using angular

Tags: angular

i have a json response and i'm displaying the text from the json response using *ngFor directive and paragraph tag.the paragraph tag has a property contentEditable,which is set to true.Now i can edit the content in the paragraph but not sure how to reflect that changes(on the screen and json response)

[image: html file][image: component file]

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for `input` event of `contenteditable` element and then grab
`innerText` from `event.target`.

```
<div *ngFor="let subtitle of subtitlesRes">
    <p contenteditable (input)="saveChanges($event)">{{subtitle.subtitleText}}</p>
</div>
```

```
saveChanges(event: InputEvent): void {
    this.subtitlesRes[0].subtitleText = (event.target as HTMLElement).innerText;
}
```